# How to show a button for only one group in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to show "Create Invoice" button in Sales Order only for one group.Is is Possible?
I've created a new group in Sales,it is Sales/Branch Head.Is is possible to hide the **" Create Invoice "** button for all users and show it only for **"Sales/ Branch Head"** group.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use groups attribute. Example from account module:

```
        <record id="view_invoice_line_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.line.tree</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice.line</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Invoice Line">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="account_id" groups="account.group_account_user"/>
                <field name="quantity"/>
                <field name="uos_id"/>
                <field name="price_unit"/>
                <field name="discount" groups="base.group_extended"/>
                <field name="price_subtotal"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Thank's for quick answer.Can you please tell me how to find out the group name of the group that i've created.

Comment: It should be xml_id for this group. It is in one of `ir.model.data` objects. It should be `module_name.id_of_group_from_xml`.

Comment: 2 possibilities to find out a xml_id (in this case for a group): 1. use openerp in debug mode and open the record (here under settings->...->groups and your group). now just use the debug menu "perm read" and you will get the xml_id | 2. go into db and look out for ir_model_data table. here you can find all xml_ids which are combined by fields "module" and "name" (module.name will be the xml_id)

Comment: To note, if you create the group from the UI you will get XML ID: false. So only groups created by modules get group IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view for all your other users without the button you want to show. And then create a other view that inherits your first view and add the button you want to show to your desired group. Here is an example I am using and is working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- ##################################################### SHOW BUTTON ONLY TO MEMBERS OF SOME_GROUP ############################################################ -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view"  id="unique_id_of_your_new_view">
            <field name="name">view.unique.id.of.your.new.view</field>
            <field name="model">your.model</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="id_of_view_youre_inheriting"/>
            <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('name_of_your_group') ])]"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="some_field_in_your_main_view" position="after">
                    <!-- whatever you will place here will be shown only to members of 'name_of_your_group' -->
                    <button name="your_button" class="oe_highlight" string="This button is not shown to everybody"  /> 
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```